# Can not find string defined in Data Area at the correct address

Tags: assembly, arm, keil, cortex-m

I have two segments defined in ARM assembly for cortex - M4, one is code (Read only) and another is data (read write). The read only memory is defined to start at address 0x08000000 and the RW memory at 0x20000000. Each segment is defined in its own assembly file and label names are exported/imported correctly.

The data segment is written as:

```
    AREA myData, Data, READWRITE
EXPORT myString

    myString DCB "To be or not to be, that is the question"
    END
```

In the code, I am loading the address of the string by using LDR R0, =myString

R0 correctly loads address 0x20000000 into R0. But when using Keil uVision IDE memory view, the memory at that address is empty. Instead, I find the string right after the code in the Read Only area. So could you please tell me how to place the string at the correct place in memory?

Thanks

Comment: your bootstrap copies/initializes .data yes?

Answer (score 3):

Are you running a C runtime before executing your assembly code? If you provide an intial value for a string it must be stored in program memory and then copied to RAM at runtime. A C runtime should do this for you, or you can do it yourself if you are only running assembly code, but it must be done explicitly.

Comment: (+1) I assume what you mean by runtime is a loader.

Answer (score 2):

The DATA area should not be used to define constants...use the CODE area for that.  This way you can access the string and read it into a register, then write it into memory if you wish.  The DATA area should be used to allocate memory to the program using the SPACE directive.

Every textbook/manual I've read claims that you can define a constant in the DATA area, but I have yet to see it functioning.

Answer (score 0):

If your have specified its segment start address in your compiler options, what is the output of

```
readelf -S
```

or

```
nm | grep myData
```